# Tensorflow iterate over tensor with one dimension = None

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a custom keras layer in tensorflow, and I need to iterate over a tensor. The problem is the tensor has shape (None, ... , ..., ...). I am not sure how to iterate over this. I tried

```
for i in range(len(x[:, 0, 0, 0])):
```

and even `tf.map_fn` but both would run an infinite number of times. How do I run iterate over a tensor with one dimension being none?

Comment: how are you getting the shape? `None` might mean the shape is just unknown, not that it's infinite (I'm not sure you can even have an infinite tensor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding more information would be helpful. What is the tensor? Your training data? tf.map_fn should still work but maybe you need to disable eager execution first like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```